# Leading zeros in Matlab char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, char, zero, leading-zero

I have an integer array that has zeros in it, but when I convert it into a char array, the leading zeros are gone. How can I have leading zeros in a char array?

For example: it prints `'  4D9'` instead of `'004D9'`. How do I print the leading zeros?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to print the integers in hexadecimal with leading zeros, you just need the leading `0` flag in the [`formatspec`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html#inputarg_formatSpec):

```
>> n = 1241;
>> s = num2str(n,'%05X')
s =
004D9
```

Comment: thank you , but it's not working with my char array even if I convert it to uint32 when I want to retrieve the char array the leading zeros still gone

Comment: @mariafrank Please post a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code.

Comment: for example I HAVE char array the first ROW of it should be  A(1,:) = `004D`   the second A(2,:) = `96FA` the first string  must be started with 2 zeros but instead of showing zeros there will be white spaces `  4D`  and when I try to save them to text file ,it will be saved as a white space,and when I call the text file it  will ignore the first string and prints only the second which is  `96FA`  how can I fix this ?

Comment: I have a char array that I want it to be in a specific size so I convert it to uint32 then I used the zero padding at the beginning to make it's size equal to the required size, after that I convert it back to char array but the zeros are gone .

Comment: @mariafrank Okay, so the leading statement in the question that you "have an integer array" was incorrect.  Have you tried `A = strrep(A,' ','0')`?

Comment: @mariafrank Then please post a minimal, complete, verifiable example of your code. Without that, I have no ability to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I go through each element in the number array and convert it to a string. I then concatenate these together

```erlang
a = [0,0,2,3,4,5,6]; 
my_str = '';

for ii=1:numel(a)
    my_str(ii) = num2str(a(ii));
end
disp(my_str)
```

this gives the output
'0023456'

Comment: thank you ,my array is a char array and this method is not working for it